# When I combine 2 onEdit scripts, I keep getting a range error on Google sheets-Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, triggers

I have a shared google sheet that I use as a to-do list. I am using Script Editor. I originally had everything moving to an empty row on sheet 1. As more was added I found that the done items need to move to a second sheet.
My original code moved the row from any input in column 6/F. I have tried adding a trigger to move column 7/G to sheet 2. Both codes work by themselves, but I cannot seem to combine them.

After researching this site and others, I have tried renaming onEdit, Nesting, using “my function”, recording macros.
I receive the same error but the line changes depending on how I edit the code. "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined onEdit @ Done.gs:2"

What I want to achieve,

When the task is marked complete it moves to sheet2 (Column 7/G type “yes”)
When the status of a task is updated it moves it to an empty row on sheet 1 (Column 6/F words used – ongoing, pending review, later)
I am also looking for a basic course to start understanding scripts and macros for google sheets. I realize that I am starting in the middle and making it harder on myself. Thank you I appreciate the feedback and recommendations!

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Sheet1
// target sheet of move to named Sheet2
// test column with yes is col 7 or G
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == "yes") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
function onEdit(e) {

const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 6  && row > 1 && !as.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
const row_new = as.getRange(row,1,1,col);
row_new.copyTo(as.getRange(as.getLastRow()+1,1,1,col));
as.deleteRow(row);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works :)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  var row = event.range.getRow();
  var col = event.range.getColumn();
  var numColumns = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
  if(activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 7 && event.value == "yes") {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    activeSheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    activeSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
  if(activeSheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 6  && row > 1 && !activeSheet.getRange(row,col).getValue()=='') {  
    var rowNew = activeSheet.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns);
    rowNew.copyTo(activeSheet.getRange(activeSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,numColumns));
    activeSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('entry');//debug
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  s.getRange('P1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));//debug
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "yes") {
    e.source.toast('cond1');//debug
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    var trg = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).copyTo(trg);
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
  if (s.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && !e.value) {
    e.source.toast('cond2');//debug
    const row_new = s.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, e.range.columnStart);
    row_new.copyTo(s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, e.range.columnStart));
    s.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

I added the tools that I generally use to debug these scripts. The toasts help me to be able to determine where the code is stopping when I edit the page.  And the line that include JSON.stringify(e) I usually put in some unused cell near the top of the page so that one can see what's inside of the event object.

Comment: This gives the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ onEdit.gs:2 **  when I use the sheet column 7/G works but Column 6/F does not.

Comment: Look  at your executions log to see if there are any errors.

Comment: This is the error I have  TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
    at onEdit(onEdit:2:13)

Comment: Well usually that happens when people  try to run it from the script editor or they forget to put the e parameter into function declaration.   The function must be receiving a correct event object from the trigger or you will get that error.

Comment: I am putting that code in on script editor. I am probably using the wrong words/tags? I am still learning. Can you point me in the right direction of where to look for this kind of input?

Comment: I added to some of the debugging code that I used when developing these types of scripts.

Comment: The updated code does not produce an error in the log but it also does not copy the rows to lower space on the sheet.  There is also a box that pops up and it is labeled Cond 1.   When I click run from script editor I receive this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Organize sheet.gs:3"